# Gitlab CI Deploy Token cant push to repo

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I am trying to copy some files from Firebase into a Gitlab repo.

Using my personal SSH credentials, I am able to do this.

I'd like to use deploy tokens. I generated a fresh token and gave it all the permissions I can. However, when I run the CI pipeline I get an "fatal: Authentication failed"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A deploy token is simply not made for that. As per the [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/deploy_tokens/) a deploy token is not capable to write to a GitLab repository. Here is what you can do with a deploy token:

1. Clone Git repositories.
2. Pull from and push to a GitLab container registry.
3. Pull from and push to a GitLab package registry.

What may be a better fit for your use case is a so called [Deploy Key](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/deploy_keys/). If the deploy key has `read-write` permissions you should be able to solve your issues.